# How to change my cursor pre-sets (schemes) with one file

Tags: windows, autohotkey, mouse-cursor

So lately I found a really good cursor preset. But sometimes I want it to be normal, or just randomly choose a scheme upon start up. My idea is to use one single file to make this modification. I looked around the settings and found out that if you change the schemes in the settings window, it will change values under the HKCU/Control Panel/Cursors. I tried to use a .reg file to write in values and use cmd to update the settings, registry data was changed, but the settings didn't apply.

I also tried to came across the idea to use AutoHotKey to change it, but really don't know how to :P

please help me to change it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=18014
This link explains how to do it with the use of AutoHotkey.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Please consider editing your post to add the steps listed in the referenced link, as referenced links can and do get broken over time!